# Replace 3V DC batteries in water heating system to Power adapter

Tags: adapter

I'm trying to replace a pair of 1.5v D size batteries that my water heater uses for ignition.

I have bought a 3V 1amp power adapter, but when I connect it to the terminals and turn on the faucet, I hear and see the sparkles from the ignitor, but that doesn't seem to trigger the gas from actually being released and burn. As soon as I unplug it and put the batteries back on, it works again.

Is there anything I might be missing?

Thanks you very much!

Comment: What makes you think 1 amp is enough.

Comment: You have a strange water heater...where on the planet are you?

Comment: Got a link to manufacturer's data for the heater? Alternatively, if you have a multimeter with a fast max function you can find the current needed.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, I'm in Brazil, and gas-powered water heaters (for showers and faucets, mainly) are fairly common.

Comment: @replete unfortunately no link (kind of old unit). I have this multimeter: http://static.mercadoshops.com/multimetro-digital-com-cabo-de-multiteste-testador-ac-dc_iZ508634590XvZxXpZ1XfZ79083866-867256521-1.jpgXsZ79083866xIM.jpg

Would that work?

Comment: Unfortunately that meter won't help much. Are you determined to solve this by yourself? If this is a one-off project and you don't plan to continue with electronics, maybe look for help from someone at a local electronics club or polytechnic. You need to measure the peak current drawn from the ignitor. If the ignitor draws a peak current of, for example, 3A then you need a power supply rated 3V and >=3A. This measurement can be done by putting a multimeter with a fast MAX function on current mode in series with the battery. It will remember the highest value seen.

Comment: Of course, another option though not technically satisfying is to simply buy another 3V supply with higher current rating and see whether it supplies enough.

Comment: are you sure that you are using a DC adapter?

Answer (score 3):

I put capacitor 10,000 micro farad (16v) in parallel with adaptor output terminals (+ to +, _ to _), it will ignite the water heater without any problem. Put the capacitor as close as battery terminals as to minimize current losses. It work for me and hope it work for you!

The current surge is just a second when the water heater start to ignite, and for this, the capacitor with big enough capacity e.g. 10,000 micro farad, can handle this surge. I am not using theory in it, just trial and error, and it works for me in the same situation and purpose.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained the purpose of the capacitor ;)